# Method not found System.String System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String, System.Object)'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following error :

> Method not found: 'System.String System.String.Format
>   (System.IFormatProvider, System.String, System.Object)

It's thrown on this line :

```
ViewBag.Title = Resources.Title;
```

`Resources.Title` is a simple string I didn't changed for monthes.

My project is in MVC4, .Net 4.5 and C# 5. I can compile without any problem, the exception is thrown when I try to access to the site. I rebuilt the project, manually cleared the output folder, but the error is still there. I installed .Net 4.6 recently, could the error come from there ?

Edit: Here is the call stack:

> [MissingMethodException: Méthode introuvable : 'System.String
>   System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String,
>   System.Object)'.]
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.BSYMMGR.GetNameFromPtrs(Object
>   u1, Object u2) +0
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.BSYMMGR.GetNsAid(NamespaceSymbol
>   ns, KAID aid) +57
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.BSYMMGR..ctor(NameManager
>   nameMgr, TypeManager typeManager) +391
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.GlobalSymbolContext..ctor(NameManager
>   namemgr) +60
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler..ctor(CController
>   pCtrl, NameManager pNameMgr) +40
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.Reset() +123
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder..ctor() +28
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.GetInstance() +101
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpSetMemberBinder..ctor(String
>   name, Boolean isCompoundAssignment, Boolean isChecked, Type
>   callingContext, IEnumerable'1 argumentInfo) +113
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.SetMember(CSharpBinderFlags
>   flags, String name, Type context, IEnumerable'1 argumentInfo) +66

[...]

> lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +244
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary'2 parameters) +434
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary'2
>   parameters) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary'2
>   parameters) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41()
>   +75 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8'1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +44 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult'1.End() +139 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +102
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>   +126 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>   +323 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>   +323 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult'1.End() +139
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +102
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20()
>   +68 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +184 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult'1.End() +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +47 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult'1.End() +151
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +47 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult'1.End() +151
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +45
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +47 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult'1.End() +151
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +40 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9651188 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: and what is Resources.Title? have you got any object in there

Comment: @RomaDoskoch Yep, I tried to debug, end the exception is exactly on the line I typed: `ViewBag.Title = Resources.Title;`
@JackM it's just a simple string I didn't change for monthes.

Comment: Without further context my best guess is that the issue is that Resouces.Title is not a string but other type

Comment: Have you tried to change Resources.Title by a constant string?

Comment: @Zalomon the error is still there, on the same line.

Comment: Post the *full* exception, including its call stack. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()`. This will show exactly where the exception was thrown and who made the erroneous call

Comment: Are you running on a .NET runtime version *before* 4.6? That particular [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906224(v=vs.110).aspx) was added in .NET 4.6. Any earlier version would throw the error you posted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: He says he is running on 4.5 and has recently installed 4.6 so I think you've hit the nail on the head. You should make that into an answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I already tried to compile against the .Net 4.6, still have the error.

Comment: @gobes not compile, *run*. What .NET runtime version are you targetting? If your web.config has a 4.5 runtime tag, or the production machine doesn't have 4.6 installed, code generated for 4.6 will fail. For example, the code generated for resources may this method. When that code gets called on a machine that doesn't have a 4.6+ runtime, it will throw

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah, I didn't though of that... but even by changing httpRuntime targetFramework to 4.6 the exception is still there.

Comment: is this error in a view or controller? If i were you I would go to the controller and assign something to the viewbag and see if I can see it in the view as I there are two things here either you need to reference System in your view or controller. also can you check if libraries are still referenced etc...

Comment: @JackM It's in a controller. I already tried to assign a hardcoded string to the viewbag, but it doesn't change a thing. I'll try to repair the framework but meh :/